# Flexbox margins between elements and zero margins to parent wrapper

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/silly-firefly-87cov

We have random number of element inside parent. Elements position themselfs as it fit using flexbox.

Problem: how to do margins only between elements and not with parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to share a CSS Grid solution with you. We can use `grid-gap` to specify the spacing between the children themselves. This allows us to remove `margin` and focus on a more declarative layout from the parent element.

```
const Parent = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
`;

const Element = styled.div`
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid green;
  color: white;
`;
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-almeida-js69m)